# Solving a triangle using the Law of Cosines

Tags: c#, geometry, trigonometry

I'm looking to solve a triangle of which I know the lengths of the 3 sides (a SSS triangle). Therefore, I want to determine if the 3 "inner" angles of a shape consisting of 3 lines = 180. If it does, then the shape must be a triangle.

I'm using the formula found on this [The Law of Cosines](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-cosine-law.html) page to solve for the angles. 
In my code I do the following:

```
private bool CalculateIfTriangle(float line1Length, float line2Length, float line3Length)
    {
        double angle1 = MathHelper.ToDegrees((float)Math.Cos(((line2Length * line2Length) + (line3Length * line3Length) - (line1Length * line1Length)) / (2 * line2Length * line3Length)));
        double angle2 = MathHelper.ToDegrees((float)Math.Cos(((line3Length * line3Length) + (line1Length * line1Length) - (line2Length * line2Length)) / (2 * line3Length * line1Length)));
        double angle3 = MathHelper.ToDegrees((float)Math.Cos(((line1Length * line1Length) + (line2Length * line2Length) - (line3Length * line3Length)) / (2 * line1Length * line2Length)));

        double total = angle1 + angle2 + angle3;
        if (total == 180)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

However, I'm not getting the correct answers (even though the shape is definitely a triangle).

I'm coding my application in C# (XNA) and I'm not sure if I'm using the MathHelper.ToDegrees method correctly.

Comment: Floating point equality.... MMMMMmmmm.

Comment: do you want to use only this method ? the easier option would be to use Hero's formula. Just a suggestion

Comment: Call me naive, but is all that this function does, return true if the three line lengths can make up a triangle? You don't need cosines or Hero's formula to determine that.

Comment: Yip someone else just suggested this. But my problem is that the application will allow the user to draw the lines anywhere and any length (the application tries to find the focal length of a camera by using the vanishing lines that can be identified in a photograph). So by sheer coincidence, the user can draw 3 lines which would technically make a triangle, when in fact the 3 lines could be parallel to each other. So I think I need to use the angles  between the lines to solve the triangle

Comment: @ Hans: Say your user draws three lines, each of 1 unit length, all parallel. You pass your check-triangle-is-valid-from-line-lengths method the values 1, 1, and 1. It returns true because they can form a valid triangle - it doesn't know they're all parallel. Whatever code you put in that method, it can't work out if the lines are parallel just from their lengths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The law is

c<sup>2</sup> = a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> - 2abcos(C)

Rearranging:

cos(C) = (a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> - c<sup>2</sup>) / 2ab

C = **cos<sup>-1</sup>** [(a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> - c<sup>2</sup>) / 2ab]

So why are you using [Math.Cos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos.aspx) instead of [Math.Acos?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.acos.aspx)

Anyway, that's one of your bugs, as others have said, you are using floating point so comparing for equality is a bit hit and miss due to rounding errors.

Also, you don't need to convert back to degrees 180 degees == pi radians.

Also, you just have to compare the lengths of the sides.  In a true triangle, the length of one side is always shorter than the sum of the lengths of the other sides (see Rawling's answer).  I suspect, your formula will probably give NaN as the answer for a non triangle because you'll end up trying to take cos<sup>-1</sup> of a number not in the range [-1 .. 1]. i.e.

(a<sup>2</sup> + b<sup>2</sup> - c<sup>2</sup>) / 2ab  > 1 or < -1

In fact I suspect that the conditions for the above formula to be in the right range are exactly when

c <= a + b

Comment: Above someone said the Law of Cosines is: c^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2abcos(C) Isn't the Law of Cosines: c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2abcos(C) [Law of Cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

Comment: user3420941 is correct. can you please edit your answer?, because cosine law is wrong https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Answer (score 3):

To check if three lengths can form a triangle, you merely need to check that

```
A + B > C
A + C > B
B + C > A
```

(or equality for a degenrate triangle).

Calculating the angles formed by such a triangle is unnecessary. If the three lengths don't form a triangle, I'm not sure the angles will even make sense.

Comment: Are your conditions for being a triangle or not being triangle?

Comment: Being a triangle. If you allow equality (which, as stated, is hit-and-miss for floating point numbers), you allow the case where the triangle is flat - the two shorter sides lie along the longer side.

Comment: Fix the comparison ! ! if you meant *sum of two sides is greater than the third*

Comment: @V4V - thanks, brain completely went. leppie, I see what you were getting at.

Comment: Thanks for that. Never even thought of this solution. But the problem I have with this solution would be that the lines are drawn by the user of the application. And they can draw a line anywhere and at any length. So by sheer coincidence, the lengths of the lines could form a triangle, even when the shape is not a triangle. That is why I have chosen to work with the degrees of the angles between the lines.

Comment: That's some crazy hyper-triangle where A+B<C etc.

Comment: @Hans - but the method you're trying to write only accepts the lengths of the three lines. If you want to check whether the lines are in fact a triangle, or... they're the correct length and angle, or... whatever else you're getting at, your method will need to be passed that information.

Comment: @spender: Can't believe I did that. Should be fixed by now. It's not often I write an answer which is the _complete_ opposite of what I mean.

Comment: @Rawling: Now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that total is a float and you compare it to 180.
Because this is normally not a good idea because floating point number can have accuracy rounding problems.

Therefor use a check with range checking, i.e.

```
if ((total > 179.9) && (total < 180.1))
```

or generally:

```
accuracy = 0.1;
if ((total > 180.0 - accuracy) && (total < 180.0 + accuracy))
```

Comment: Yeah I thought my answers would be slightly off but the way it is at the moment, the answers I get are way off, by at least 40 degrees or  more.

Comment: Ok in that case use the solution as expressed by another (but still I would suggest to use this way of checking instead of directly against an integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 lines which intersect two-by-two you don't need trigonometry to determine that they form a triangle.  By not using trig you avoid the error of comparing a floating-point value for equality (eg `total==180`).  Since your don't specify the nature of the errors you have, only that you're not getting the correct answer, and since your code looks OK, this might be the source of your problem.

Unasked-for advice: why bother converting to degrees until you absolutely have to ?  You could make things briefer (and easier to comprehend) if you worked in radians until you want to present the results in degrees.

Comment: No my answers are way off, by at least 40 degrees at a time. Also no real reason for converting to degrees for each line, but what you say about leaving the converting till the last moment makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

It's highly unlikely that all that fp maths will yield exactly 180 degrees. There'll be a small amount of error that creeps in.

Comment: -1: Failure to read the question. You can see he converts the radians to degrees with some helper method.

Comment: Editing your question does not make the original assumption correct.

Comment: @leppie: The answer is now true as far as it goes, although it is not the complete answer to the question.  I think the -1 is now a bit harsh.